# extjs combobox model

Tags: extjs, combobox

Is there a way to bind a store to a ExtJS ComboBox without creating a js model (ExtJS 4.1)? 
To populate a users combobox I'll always need to set up the model first? I would like to skip the following code for each combobox:

```
Ext.define('User',{extend:'Ext.data.Model',idProperty:'Id',fields:['Id','Name']});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right, Neil!
I've found how to use it:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields:['Id','Name'],
    data:[
        {Id:0,Name:'Yes'},
        {Id:1,Name:'No'},
        {Id:2,Name:'Maybe'}
    ]
});

var pnl = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'My Panel',
    items: [{
        id:'cboField1'
        xtype:'combobox',
        fieldLabel:'My Field',
        displayField:'Name',
        valueField:'Id',
        queryMode:'local',
        store: myStore
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Architect you can specify an array in the store property for the ComboBox. There is no point to create extra stores & models if you just want a static 'Title' ComboBox.

```
xtype:'combo',
fieldLabel:'Title',
name:'division',
queryMode:'local',
store:['Mr','Mrs','Ms'],
displayField:'title',
autoSelect:true,
forceSelection:true
```

p.s. In order to change the store property to a local array in Architect you need to select the little icon on the left of the store text and change it to an array instead of a store.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found it useful to create simple model with two fields id, name and then use this model on all static stores (which I use for comboboxes) where list of values is predefined.

Answer (score 1):

You do not *need* to set a model in a store in any situation in Extjs. Set the fields property of the store.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-fields

Also, consider the data property of the store for local data.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-data